# What exactly is the `in` keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have seen the `in` keyword in many different codes but i have never understood what they do.
Here is an example

```
let duck = new Bird() // Bird is a constructor i made. Not important
function in keyword() {
    let ownProps = [];

for (let property in duck) {
  if(duck.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    ownProps.push(property);
  }
}
}
```

Sooo, what does it do?
Please explain it to me

Comment: This is something you could very quickly determine from any JavaScript resource on the Internet.

Comment: Also the code you posted is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` operator tests if the string on the left side of the operator is a property name in the object on the right side.

```
let obj = { a: 1 };
console.log("a" in obj); // true
console.log("b" in obj); // false
```

The `in` keyword also plays a role in the `for ... in` loop, which iterates through the properties (the *enumerable* properties) of an object:

```
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
for (let x in obj) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

That will log "a" and "b", because those are the enumerable properties of the object.